# Drop specific lines after index in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like follows:

```
             colA   colB     colC
entry                                                                                             
entry1        0      0        0
entry2        1      3        5
entry3        0      0        0 
entry4        0      5        5
entry5        0      2        2
entry6        3      1        1
entry7        1      2        5
entry8        3      4        1
entry9        1      2        2
entry10       2      0        0
entry11       5      5        0 
entry12       3      2        2
entry13       5      3        3
```

I would like to remove the entries from df which have colB and colC values = 0.
I have tried the following syntax:

```
for i in range(len(df.index)):
    if df['colB'][i] == 0 and df['colC'][i] == 0:
       df = df.drop(df.index[i])
```

With the set of data from above, I get the following error:

```
    if df['colB'][i] == 0 and df['colC'][i] == 0:
  File "/home/dante/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 879, in __getitem__
    return self._values[key]
IndexError: index 12 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 12
```

Any idea what it is wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use loc accessor and check your condition and then filter out rows:

```
df=df.loc[~df[['colB','colC']].eq(0).all(axis=1)]
#OR
df=df.loc[df[['colB','colC']].ne(0).any(axis=1)]
```

OR

instead of using `any()`/`all()` you can use seperate condition for both columns:

```
df=df.loc[df['colB'].ne(0) & df['colC'].ne(0)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works. I prefer the last method without `any` as it is much shorter and more understandable.